# How to force mxGraph to keep end-points of Edges from merging together

Tags: edges, mxgraph

I am creating an mxGraph based off of the [mxGraph example called folding.html](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/folding.html). The folding of the nested vertexes does exactly what I want, but I do not like how the edges merge together into one port - I want the edges to look like the [mxGraph example called autolayout.html](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/autolayout.html)

The layout of the folding.html example uses mxStackLayout and the layout of the autolayout.html example uses mxHierarchicalLayout, but I'm not sure if that matters towards my end goal.

Is there an mxGraph setting/option that causes the edges to behave like the autolayout.html example or are the edges behaving as such because of the type of layout that is used? - i.e. Is it possible to use the mxStackLayout and have the edges behave like the mxHierarchicalLayout?

[image: screenshot examples]